# How get all directories on hard drive (c#)?

Tags: c#, getdirectories

How can I get all directories (with sub directories) on hardrive using c#?

Example of response:

```
C:\
C:\1
C:\2
C:\2\1
C:\2\1\4
C:\2\1\4\5
C:\2\1\4\5\6
C:\3
```

Comment: Is there anything you have attempted already?

Comment: [How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: i'm new in c#. I tried to make this one, but unsuccessfully

Comment: If you've tried, even if it wasn't a success, edit your question to include your attempt so far.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.IO;

var directories = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

directories.ForEach(directory => Console.WriteLine(directory));
```

Answer (score 0):

Justin's answer would 100% work.  In case this is more about learning a technique than getting a result, you'll need a recursive function.  All that means is we need a function that will call itself on the results it returns.

```
public static void GetDirectories(string path, bool recursive)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path); // write the name of the current directory
    if (recursive) // if we want to get subdirectories
    { 
        try // getting directories will throw an error if it is a path you don't have access to
        {
            foreach (var child in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) // get all the subdirectories for the given path
            {
                GetDirectories(child, recursive); // call our function for each sub directory
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) // handle unauthorized access errors
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("You don't have permission to view subdirectories of {0}",path));
        }

    }
}
```

And then to call it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetDirectories("c:\\", true);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Again if you are just trying to get the list go with Justin's answer, but this is how you could do it on your own.